# i want sqlite3.node file of version 83 from nod.js v8.3

Tags: node.js, node-modules, node-sqlite3

My node application is currently running in node version 8.3. I am getting above error of missing **\node-v83-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node**' module in node_modules. When i try to install the same by running `npm install --save sqlite3`. I am getting below error to update node version to latest.

```
node-pre-gyp ERR! install error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: The Node-API version of this Node instance is 1. This module supports Node-API version(s) 3,6. This Node instance cannot run this module.
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Object.module.exports.validate_package_json (C:\Users\DELL\sqlll\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\napi.js:82:11)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at validate_config (C:\Users\DELL\sqlll\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\versioning.js:229:8)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Object.module.exports.evaluate (C:\Users\DELL\sqlll\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\versioning.js:279:3)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at install (C:\Users\DELL\sqlll\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\install.js:190:25)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Object.self.commands.(anonymous function) [as install] (C:\Users\DELL\sqlll\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\node-pre-gyp.js:86:37)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at run (C:\Users\DELL\sqlll\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\main.js:81:30)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\DELL\sqlll\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\main.js:125:1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22621
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\DELL\\sqlll\\node_modules\\@mapbox\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\DELL\sqlll\node_modules\sqlite3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.3.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.11
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
The Node-API version of this Node instance is 1. This module supports Node-API version(s) 3,6. This Node instance cannot run this module.
npm WARN Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:\Users\DELL\sqlll\node_modules\minizlib\node_modules'
npm WARN  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:\Users\DELL\sqlll\node_modules\minizlib\node_modules'
npm WARN   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir \'C:\\Users\\DELL\\sqlll\\node_modules\\minizlib\\node_modules\'',
npm WARN   errno: -4048,
npm WARN   code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN   syscall: 'scandir',
npm WARN   path: 'C:\\Users\\DELL\\sqlll\\node_modules\\minizlib\\node_modules' }
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sqlite3@5.1.6 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@5.1.6 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-17T16_28_25_605Z-debug.log
```

Updating node version and running the install command is giving me sqlite3.node file of that node version.

I need sqlite3.node file of node.js 8.3. Can somebody help in getting this module. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What?! You need to upgrade Node.js version *ASAP* if your application is on production! Node.js 8 is **NO LONGER** maintained.